# Undefined method [model]_url for nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3

I am working on a nested resources project, and am getting an error in my steps controller:

```
  def create
    @step = Step.new(step_params)

    respond_to do |f|
      if @step.save
        f.html { redirect_to @step, notice: 'Step was successfully created.' }
        f.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @step }
      else
        f.html { render action: 'new' }
        f.json { render json: @step.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The error I am getting is:

```
undefined method `step_url' for #<StepsController:0x007feeb6442198>
```

My routes looks like this:

```
root 'lists#index'

resources :lists do
  resources :steps
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you are using nested resources, update the create action as below:

```
  def create
    @list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    @step = @list.steps.build(step_params) ## Assuming that list has_many steps

    respond_to do |f|
      if @step.save
        ## update the url passed to redirect_to as below
        f.html { redirect_to list_step_url(@list,@step), notice: 'Step was successfully created.' }
        f.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @step }
      else
        f.html { render action: 'new' }
        f.json { render json: @step.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Run `rake routes` to see the available routes.
As route to steps#show would look something like

```
GET lists/:list_id/steps/:id steps#show
```

Use `list_step_url` with 2 arguments `@list` For :list_id and `@step` for :id to go to show page of Step.